# How to get Alexa audience geography using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the top 3 countries from Alexa report but I am unable to access the site using `curl`. But when I do I am getting an error from Alexa telling me to sign up with Amazon. I know `curl` is unblockable but they seem to have done it.

```
$url="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo('<textarea>'.$result.'</textarea>');
```

Comment: Are you doing this from a server of some sort? Or your local machine? I'd bet they've blacklisted a variety of cloud hosting services.

Comment: yeah, this seems to be what happened. works for godaddy tho :)

Comment: @JakeGould I know StackExchange blocks AWS EC2 IP ranges, as an example. Sometimes there's just too much abuse/scraping coming from a service to allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Note I used a standard set of curl options I like to use. Feel free to adjust based on your actual needs. The reason I did that is because while you are setting `$agent` you are not actually passing that to `curl` in any way. So my options properly sets `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` as well as a few other things.

```
$url ="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com";
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo('<textarea>'.$result.'</textarea>');
```

And here are my results from my local test environment where I am using PHP 5.4 via MAMP on a Macintosh.

[image]

**EDIT:** According to the original poster, this script works on one host but not another where he is met with a “403: Forbidden” error. Which points to some kind of blocking happening on the Alexa server.  I would recommend debugging by using `curl -I` from the command line like this:

```
curl -I http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com
```

And on my local Mac OS X 10.9.4 setup, I get this in response to the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 01:24:51 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: rpt=%21; expires=Fri, 11-Jul-2014 02:24:51 GMT; domain=alexa.com
Set-Cookie: lv=1404955491; expires=Fri, 10-Jul-2015 07:24:51 GMT; path=/; domain=alexa.com
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: keep-alive
```

The `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` means all is good. If you run the same command from the command line & get anything other than that, you can bet you are being blocked. Possibly a block based just on an IP range.  Or even blocked via something like ModSecurity which would do heuristic analysis of traffic to catch & block non-standard web requests. Regardless, if you are being blocked on the server side of this, there is not much you can do to unblock yourself.

That said, note how I properly set `$agent` in my version of the script but you didn’t? It could be in your testing you ran so many `curl` requests without a proper user agent while testing your IP is now temporarily blocked. So wait a day or two & try again but with my version of the script so a proper user agent is set. I bet it will work fine then.

Comment: This is also returning "Forbidden"

Comment: your source in the textarea are the same as it would be if you went to the url and viewed source from browser? im geting a page redirect when using curl

Comment: hmmm, i just tried it on another host and it worked fine. now im all confused!

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is a simple coding error, try the following:

```
$url="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo '<textarea>'.$result.'</textarea>';
```

You missed the periods (.) after the `'<textarea>'` and before the `'</textarea>'` to make it include them, and the `echo` function doesn't require parenthesis.

I have tested this and it worked for me.

Comment: ooops, sorry about that but it still does not work. ;\ it is returning  "Forbidden" but if you goto that url in a browser it works fine. its some how blocking curl

Comment: Do you have all the php curl modules installed? Also, are you running a server with Apahce or something else?

Comment: yes its working, but it seems they are blocking me or my curl is configured diffrently. i can use it with other domains but not alexa. this code also worked for me on another host.